# Coordinate map from cotangent space is smooth

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I know that for a given coordinate system of the tangent space $\partial_1,..,\partial_n$ the coordinate map is smooth, as the coordinate map $\pi_i$ of ${T_xM}$ is nothing but the composition of the chart and coordinate map in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and both of them are smooth. Unfortunately, this is less clear to me if we are talking about the cotangent space, cause then I have a coordinate system $dx_1,..,dx_n$ , but how do I see that now the coordinate projection is still smooth?

If anything is unclear, please let me know.

Comment: You can look at Lee's book "Introduction to smooth manifolds", chapter 11 on the cotangent bundle.

Comment: Could you explain your sentence "the coordinate map $\pi_i$ of $T_xM$ is nothing but the composition of the chart and coordinate map in $\mathbb{R}^n$"?

Comment: I guess you want to show that certain (maybe only locally defined) maps $T^*M\to\mathbb{R}$ are smooth (namely the coordinate projections). In particular, you need a smooth structure on $T^*M$. Which definition of the smooth structure on $T^*M$ are you using?